# When a receiver method T cannot take *T?

Tags: go

The official Go site [writes as follows](https://golang.org/doc/faq#different_method_sets):

> As the Go specification says, the method set of a type T consists of
>   all methods with receiver type T, while that of the corresponding
>   pointer type *T consists of all methods with receiver *T or T. That
>   means the method set of *T includes that of T, but not the reverse.
>
> This distinction arises because if an interface value contains a
>   pointer *T, a method call can obtain a value by dereferencing the
>   pointer, but if an interface value contains a value T, there is no
>   safe way for a method call to obtain a pointer. (Doing so would allow
>   a method to modify the contents of the value inside the interface,
>   which is not permitted by the language specification.)
>
> **Even in cases where the compiler could take the address of a value to
>   pass to the method**, if the method modifies the value the changes will
>   be lost in the caller.

My question is, when **can't** the compiler take a value to a pointer receiver value?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/40828156/1256452: Why interface don't implement method with pointer reference while direct access is still possible? - does that cover the cases you're wondering about?

Comment: "when can't the compiler take a value to a pointer receiver value?" As explained in the second paragraph cited from the spec: Always. If you are interested in part marked bold in the spec: Some things are not addressable, e.g. a function: It is impossible to take the address of function. (if you are new to Go: This is pretty much uninteresting.)

Answer (score 1):

Addressable is defined in the https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators:

> For an operand x of type T, the address operation &x generates a pointer of type *T to x. The operand must be *addressable*, that is, either a variable, pointer indirection, or slice indexing operation; or a field selector of an addressable struct operand; or an array indexing operation of an addressable array. As an exception to the addressability requirement, x may also be a (possibly parenthesized) composite literal.

A counter examples include map values and functions:

```
func f() {}

func main() {
    var m map[string]string
    p1 := &m["foo"] // cannot take the address of m["foo"]
    p2 := &f        // cannot take the address of f
}
```